# Gutenberg additional block attributes

Tags: wordpress, rest, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

I’m building an application in React and for the first time I want to use WP REST. I am using gutenberg, and I’m successfully getting the blocks in rest. I have a problem with building my own blocks though, I need to append additional data to them, and I already spent few hours searching and trying to read source code for other blocks. How do I add these “attrs” fields?[image]

Answer (score 0):

you check below link for more information.

https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/block-api/attributes/